# How to create an Oracle One-to-Many Statistics View？

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have three tables need to join statistics.The `A table` corresponds to multiple rows in the `B table`, and B has a state. I need to count the number of scrapped statuses in B and some attributes of the rows in non-rejected state, and finally `grouped by` A's barcode, but I don't know how to query B in different states in a query and count them in an A. I tried following codes, but nothing queried.

```
select 
    a.barcode barcode
    , count(b.id) effectiveNum
    , count(b2.id) scraps
    , sum(b.x * c.y)
from A a
    , B b
    , B b2
    , C c
where a.id = b.Aid 
and a.id = b2.Aid 
and b2.state = -1000 
and b.id = c.Bid
group by a.barcode
```

Who can help me please?

Comment: Please post some sample input data and desired output derived from the sample. It will help us to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to LEFT-JOIN in order to accept empty Lists in B. But as APC said, some example-data would be great.

```
SELECT a.barcode   barcode,
         COUNT (b.id) effectiveNum,
         COUNT (b2.id) scraps,
         SUM (b.x * c.y)
    FROM A a
         LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.Ai
         LEFT JOIN B b2 ON a.id = b2.Aid AND b2.state = -1000
         LEFT JOIN C c ON b.id = c.Bid
   WHERE 1 = 1 -- Filter A here if needed
GROUP BY a.barcode
```